# With HTTPS-Enforcer chrome extension, a normal ping is answered by different site

Tags: security, https, ping, google-chrome

I have installed the [HTTP-Enforcer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beaholcfmnpbabojbldnhlikfmnjmoma) chrome extension. Now if I open a terminal and type `ping google.com` I see:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com.home (67.215.65.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from kcherenkov.github.com.home (67.215.65.132): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=293 ms
```

`kcherenkov` is the github user that authored the extension.

Should I be concerned that a chrome extension has affected network traffic from the terminal? Should I also be concerned about any privacy issues with this setup?

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search home
```

Yes, I did configure the system to use OpenDNS at one time and it's still in effect. Why though would it resolve google.com to the github site of a plugin used by chrome?

Comment: How could a *browser extension* affect the network stack so deeply? Wouldn't this require a change to the resolver or installation of a proxy, which tends to require superuser/administrative privileges?

Comment: This is weird, could you please post the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Okay it's obvious now that your system uses a custom DNS server installed on it (`namserver` is set to the default local address `127.0.0.1`). Again, 67.215.65.132 is NOT a github site of that plugin, it is one of the OpenDNS IP addresses according to its whois info (you can check this using `whois 67.215.65.132`). The easiest way to fix it temporarily is to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` manually and to replace `nameserver 127.0.0.1` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (`8.8.8.8` is a Google public DNS). To make this fix permanent you should consult `resolvconf` manual, I'm not a big expert here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, `67.215.65.132` is an address from `opendns.com` IP adresses block as I just discovered using `whois`, so the situation seems to be totally unrelated to the Chrome extension. It looks like you are using OpenDNS and it replaced the default resolver with its custom one. This should be OK if you trust this company (and I assume you do).

Comment: +1 Was firing up a VM to play with the extension to see what it did but my machine crashed...  This is a much better answer than jumping to conclusions like I was doing.

Comment: If you remove the extension, do you still get the same behavior with ping? You probably do, but sometimes it's nice to see a confirmation.

Comment: Now, whether the extension is enabled, disabled or removed the ping of `google.com` says `$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.135.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from chrome.google.com (74.125.135.113): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=199 ms` _chrome_.google.com ?